# receiving RTP stream on RPi

Tags: opencv, streaming-video, streaming, gstreamer

Need to receive RTP stream with lowest possible latency and CPU load. I need to always read the latest frame, that is, as if I had a buffer equal to 1. What is the best way? I need it to be possible to read this frame later using OpenCV in C++. I have tried pipeline with Gstreamer or ffmpeg but the latency is quite high

Answer (score 0):

Create and connect to a VPN server on your LAN or whatever network the stream is on. Type in the port and machine with the stream into your browser. Do what you will with stream, capture, whatever.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).